# Replacing missing value blank space with zero

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

I have input.txt tab-delimited text file around 30K lines, I would like to check each row (s1..s30K lines) for missing value (i.e blank space) and fill the missing value with zero value.See out.txt

input.txt

```
 id  no1  no2  no3  no4
 s1  23   34   45   12
 s2       4    4      
 s3  4         8    0
```

out.txt

```
id  no1  no2  no3  no4
s1  23   34   45   12
s2  0     4    4    0  
s3  4     0    8    0
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do it like this with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1' file
```

#### Explanation

Setting FS and OFS to tab ensures the output is correctly delimited. The for-loop looks at every field and sets it to zero if it is empty. The one at the end is a shorthand for `{ print $0 }`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer:

```
sed 's/<TAB> /<TAB>0/g' <input.txt >output.txt
```

Replace `<TAB>` with the real TAB character (generally obtained by hitting <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>)