# How to replace empty cells of a specific column

Tags: awk, replace, columns

I have a file with many columns and some empty cells in different columns. I would like to replace the empty cells for NA only in the third column. 
My file:

```
1 id1 info 
2     otherinfo
3 id2
4     noinfo
5 id3
6 id4 info2
```

So the output should be:

```
1 id1 info 
2     otherinfo
3 id2 NA
4     noinfo
5 id3 NA
6 id4 info2
```

I tried this command ([Replacing missing value blank space with zero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53448/replacing-missing-value-blank-space-with-zero)), but it replaced all empty cells.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Change the spaces separating the data into tabs, then you can use tabs as your delimiter and see the empty column more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]' '$2 && !$3{ $3="NA" }1' file
```

The output:

```
1 id1 info 
2     otherinfo
3 id2 NA
4     noinfo
5 id3 NA
6 id4 info2
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand the command. If my column is not the third, but the 10th for example, the command will be: awk -F'[[:space:]]' '$9 && !$10{ $10="NA" }1'  ?

Comment: @Paul, presumably, yes

Answer (score 3):

If your file has fixed-width columns, you can parse them in GNU awk with `FIELDWIDTHS`, e.g.:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='1 1 3 1 99' -v OFS="" '!$5 { $5 = " NA" } 1' infile
```

Output:

```
1 id1 info
2     otherinfo
3 id2 NA
4     noinfo
5 id3 NA
6 id4 info2
```

Comment: nice. i didn't even know about FIELDWIDTHS until now, and i've been writing awk/gawk scripts for decades.

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` works for me:

```
sed -E 's/(.*id[0-9]{1,}$)/\1 NA/'
```

Example:

```
sed -E 's/(.*id[0-9]{1,}$)/\1 NA/' NA.txt 
1 id1 info 
2     otherinfo
3 id2 NA
4     noinfo
5 id3 NA
6 id4 info2
```

Where `NA.txt` is this file:

```
cat NA.txt 
1 id1 info 
2     otherinfo
3 id2
4     noinfo
5 id3
6 id4 info2
```

Comment: I do not need to include the info of the third column here?

Comment: Umm... I'm not sure I follow. I used your example file, and this is the result.

Comment: My question is if I can apply the same logic to another column. I included here just an example, I have many columns. The one that I need to replace is not the third actually.