# Filling empty cells and making data type the same in a tab separated file

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

I am dealing with a tab separated file with nearly 200MM rows on Linux. In one the columns which contains binary values, I noticed the data type is not consistent and there is a large number of missing values. Here is an example:

input:

```
timestamp    val
1589205592   0  
1589205593   0.0
1589205594  
1589205595   1
1589205595   1.0
```

I tried what was suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53448/replacing-missing-value-blank-space-with-zero) using awk, but seems it can be really slow since the file size is large. I am trying to fill these values with 0, make the data types consistent i.e., convert all float to  int, and overwrite the current file.

output:

```
timestamp    val
1589205592   0  
1589205593   0
1589205594   0
1589205595   1
1589205595   1
```

Comment: Will the tab always be present, even if you don't have data in the second field? Or do you have lines with no tab, just the first field? Do you want all decimals removed, or only `.0`? What if you have `1.00`? Should that also become `1`? I assume you don't want to change if the value is `1.06`, right? Or do you want to round the numbers to the closest integer value? What is the "data type" and how is it not consistent? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon- Thanks for your suggestion and comment. I edited the post.

Comment: @Kusalananda. I wish I could:)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR > 1 { $2 = sprintf("%d", $2) }; 1' file >file.new
```

This would read your data and write it to a new file with all the number in the second column converted to integers (by rounding down, missing data would be turned into zeros).

If you want floating point output, e.g. with two decimal places, use `%.2f` in place of `%d` as the format string in the call to `sprintf()`.

The output will be tab-delimited.

Once you've inspected the new file by eye, simply `mv` it in place of the old file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
mlr --csvlite --fs tab put '$val = is_empty($val) ? 0 : int($val)' file
```

Miller provides an [in-place mode](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html#In-place_mode) should you wish to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Or inline with `sed` (just add the `-i` though it has the temp file overhead too)

```
sed -e "s/\.0$//" -e "s/\t$/\t0/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do:

```
gawk -i inplace -F'\t' 'NR>1{ $2*=1 }1' OFS='\t' infile
```

however `-i inplace` doesn't do such magic and it creates a temp file then replaces after process ends. so you can also do

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{ $2*=1 }1' OFS='\t' infile > newfile
```

then either remove original infile or rename newfile with original infile.